# Добавить возможность автоматического добавления надписи ко всем изображениям заданного формата в выбранной директории (с учетом вложенных папок)

Tags: c#

Вот задание: "Создать приложение, которое позволяет добавлять указанному изображению 
заданную надпись (шрифт, размер, цвет, координаты указывает 
пользователь). **Добавить возможность автоматического добавления надписи 
ко всем изображениям заданного формата в выбранной директории (с учетом 
вложенных папок)**." я сделал половину, а вот что выделено шрифтом, никак не получается, если есть у кого-то идеи буду рад выслушать их, спасибо!

P.S: для одной фотографии я сделал, всё работает. Теперь нужно, чтобы user писал в textbox символы(которые будут добавляться на фотографию) выбирал формат фотографии "*.JPG" or "*.PNG" и тд. и нажимал кнопку, и после этого, программа прошла по всей директории, нашла нужные файлы, написала на них символы (из textbox) и сохранила это в той же папке.

```
namespace GUI
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        Image MemForImage;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // ОТКРЫТИЕ
        {
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "All Files (*.*)| *.*| Image Files(*.JPG)|*.JPG| Image Files(*.GIF)|*.GIF| Image Files(*.PNG)|*.PNG | Image Files(*.BMP)|*.BMP";

            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                try // безопасная попытка 
                {
                    MemForImage = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);   // пытаемся загрузить файл с именем openFileDialog1.FileName - выбранный пользователем файл.
                    pictureBox1.Image = MemForImage;// устанавливаем картинку в поле элемента PictureBox 
                }
                catch (Exception ex) // если попытка загрузки не удалась 
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Не удалось загрузить файл: " + ex.Message);// выводим сообщение с причиной ошибки 
                }

            }
            buttonText.Visible = true;
            buttonTextColor.Visible = true;
            buttonTextFont.Visible = true;
            textBox1.Visible = true;
            textBoxOX.Visible = true;
            textBoxOY.Visible = true;
            textBoxX.Visible = true;
            textBoxY.Visible = true;
            buttonAll.Visible = true;

    }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //СОХРАНЕНИЕ
        {
            if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
            {
                Bitmap bmpSave = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.DisplayRectangle.Width, pictureBox1.DisplayRectangle.Height);
                pictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(bmpSave, pictureBox1.DisplayRectangle);
                SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
                sfd.DefaultExt = "bmp";
                sfd.Filter = "All Files (*.*)| *.*| Image Files(*.JPG)|*.JPG| Image Files(*.GIF)|*.GIF| Image Files(*.PNG)|*.PNG | Image Files(*.BMP)|*.BMP";
                if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    bmpSave.Save(sfd.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                }
            }

        }

        private void buttonClean_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // ОЧИЩЕНИЕ
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = null;
            textBox1.Text = null;
            buttonText.Visible = false;
            buttonTextColor.Visible = false;
            buttonTextFont.Visible = false;
            textBox1.Visible = false;
            textBoxOX.Visible = false;
            textBoxOY.Visible = false;
            textBoxX.Visible = false;
            textBoxY.Visible = false;
            buttonAll.Visible = false;
        }

        public void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            int i = Int32.Parse(textBoxOX.Text);
            int j = Int32.Parse(textBoxOY.Text);

            e.Graphics.DrawString(textBox1.Text, textBox1.Font, new SolidBrush(colorDialog1.Color), new Point (i,j)); //перерисовка текста
        }

        private void buttonText_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.Invalidate(); //команда на перерисовку текста
        }

        private void buttonTextFont_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (fontDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBox1.Font = fontDialog1.Font; //Меняет шрифт 
            }               
        }

        public void buttonTextColor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (colorDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBox1.ForeColor = colorDialog1.Color;
            }
        } 
    }     
}
```

Comment: Если вы смогли добавить это для 1 изображения, какие проблемы с тем, чтобы добавить это для 2, 3 или всех изображений из папки?

Comment: я не понял. Вы пишете, что у вас не получается `Добавить возможность автоматического добавления надписи ко всем изображениям заданного формата в выбранной директории (с учетом вложенных папок)`, а после пишете про какой то текст. Сформулируйте пожалкйста вопрос, что конкретно не получатся, что пробовали, какие были результаты ваших попыток - и добавьте это не в комментарий, а в вопрос. Вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) есть небольшая подсказка о том, как задавать вопросы. Я просто решил, что вы для одного изображения всё сделали и у вас проблемы применить это к папке.

Comment: Когда кросспостите вопрос на разных сайтах, нужно давать перекрестные ссылки: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353/В-чем-проблема-одинаковых-вопросов-на-разных-ресурсах Ответил [здесь](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/34cd351a-cf3f-4b9c-ba44-7cfb431aa5d0/1055105610541045105010581067-1057-gui-c?forum=fordesktopru)

Answer (score 0):

ну, почти автоматизация как по мне ^_^

```
private void buttonAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int o = 2;

        {
            openFileDialog1.Filter = comboBox1.Text;

            for (int i = 0; i < o; i++)
            {
                if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    try // безопасная попытка 
                    {
                        MemForImage = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);   // пытаемся загрузить файл с именем openFileDialog1.FileName - выбранный пользователем файл.
                        pictureBox1.Image = MemForImage;// устанавливаем картинку в поле элемента PictureBox 
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex) // если попытка загрузки не удалась 
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Не удалось загрузить файл: " + ex.Message);// выводим сообщение с причиной ошибки 
                    }
                }

                PaintEventArgs p = new PaintEventArgs(pictureBox1.CreateGraphics(), pictureBox1.Bounds); //Компонент на котором нужно рисовать и область на которой нужно рисовать
                pictureBox1_Paint(sender, p);
                pictureBox1.Invalidate();

                if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
                {
                    Bitmap bmpSave = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.DisplayRectangle.Width, pictureBox1.DisplayRectangle.Height);
                    pictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(bmpSave, pictureBox1.DisplayRectangle);
                    SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
                    sfd.DefaultExt = "bmp";
                    sfd.Filter = "All Files (*.*)| *.*| Image Files(*.JPG)|*.JPG| Image Files(*.GIF)|*.GIF| Image Files(*.PNG)|*.PNG| Image Files(*.BMP)|*.BMP";
                    if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        bmpSave.Save(sfd.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```